# The type or namespace name 'var' could not be found in asp.net 2.0

Tags: linq, visual-studio-2005, asp.net-2.0

I am using Asp.Net 2.0.I was trying to built an application on how to build a [Store Locator ASP.NET Application Using Google Maps API](https://web.archive.org/web/20210927201156/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/051910-1.aspx).When I am trying to use "var" in the pplication it is giving error "The type or namespace name 'var' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)".

I have downloaded  the above article and is working correctly in vs2005.I wonder why the error comes in my project only ??

Namespace i have used in the application

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Linq;
```

Heres the class i have used

```
public static XElement GetGeocodingSearchResults(string address)
{
    // Use the Google Geocoding service to get information about the user-entered address
    // See http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/index.html for more info...
    var url = String.Format("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address={0}&sensor=false", HttpContext.Current.Server.UrlEncode(address));

    // Load the XML into an XElement object (whee, LINQ to XML!)
    var results = XElement.Load(url);

    // Check the status
    var status = results.Element("status").Value;
    if (status != "OK" && status != "ZERO_RESULTS")
        // Whoops, something else was wrong with the request...
        throw new ApplicationException("There was an error with Google's Geocoding Service: " + status);

    return results;
}
```

The errors i am getting are as follows

```
Error 1 : The type or namespace name 'var' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Error 2 : The best overloaded method match for 'System.Xml.Linq.XElement.Load(string)' has some invalid arguments

Error 3:cannot convert from 'var' to 'string'
```

Comment: var wasn't introduced until C# 3.0. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx

Answer (score 0):

[var](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) keyword is not available in .NET 2.0 (C# 2.0).

It is only available in C# 3.0 onwards. This is C# language feature and not available in older versions.

Comment: I have downloaded and installed .net3.5 framework in my web.config.Will it make a difference.

Comment: Also i have downloaded the code  provided in the above application and its working perfectly..